# Any ideas for an efficient sorting/nesting algorithm for these objects?

Tags: node.js, algorithm, sorting, nested

I'd like to find some sort of efficient and logical way to quickly sort a big list of objects as such:
Input is a big list of objects with key-value pairs and each one has a "depth" key which is a 0, 1, 2, or 3. That describes how "deep into the nest" it is meant to go. I want to make a new list of these objects nested correctly as shown in the example below:

Input:

```
[
    {
        "key": "valuea",
        "depth": 0
    },
    {
        "key": "valueb",
        "depth": 1
    },
    {
        "key": "valuec",
        "depth": 2
    },
    {
        "key": "valued",
        "depth": 0
    },
    {
        "key": "valuee",
        "depth": 1
    },
    {
        "key": "valuef",
        "depth": 1
    }
]
```

And here is the desired output

```
[
    {
        "key": "valuea",
        "depth": 0,
        "tasks": [
            {
                "key": "valueb",
                "depth": 1,
                "tasks": [
                    {
                        "key": "valuec",
                        "depth": 2
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "key": "valued",
        "depth": 0,
        "tasks": [
            {
                "key": "valuee",
                "depth": 1
            },
            {
                "key": "valuef",
                "depth": 1
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Originally I was thinking of iterating through each of these values and comparing them to the value before but then I got stumped on a roadblock when thinking about a situation where you have two of the same depth in a row like "0, 1, 1." Worth noting the order matters here because the depth is nested in the previous object with a lower depth.

Comment: What are your thoughts? Please don't expect the community to do your homework for you. Explain what your thoughts on the matter are .

Answer (score 0):

```
function nestByDepth(milestones) {
    let result = [];
    let depths = [result];
    for (let task of milestones) {
        depths[task.depth].push(task);
        depths.splice(task.depth + 1); //should remove all elements at indices greater than task.depth
        task["tasks"] = [];
        depths.push(task.tasks);
    }
}
```